# How to Save full webapge in Chrome headless

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

Is there a command to save a webpage (complete) in Chrome headless?

*.Html, not *.pdf.

I want to do it using Chrome, not wget, curl, etc.

Also I'm using Windows, so 'automate-save-page-as' isn't an option.